# Number of $x$ with $x^x \equiv -a \textrm{ (mod } p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As the question states, I'm trying to understand the number of $x$s satisfying $x^x \equiv -a \textrm{ (mod } p)$ for some given $a$ over all primes $p$.

By Euler's Theorem we know that we only need to consider $x \textrm{ mod } p(p-1)$, but I'm struggling to understand how many and which $x$ satisfy this.

For example, let $a=2$.

Then $p=3$ gives $x^x \equiv 1 \textrm{ mod } 3$ iff $x \equiv 1,2,4 \textrm{ mod } 6$

$p=5$ gives $x^x \equiv 3 \textrm{ mod } 5$ iff $x \equiv 7, 13 \textrm{ mod } 20$

$p=7$ gives $x^x \equiv 5 \textrm{ mod } 7$ iff $x \equiv 17, 19 \textrm{ mod } 42$.

While these are easily calculable by a computer, I'm looking to understand primarily how many $x$ one should expect to satisfy this condition mod $p(p-1)$ (and, of course, what these values are).

Edit: There's also at least $\phi(\phi(p))$ $x$s because there are $\phi(\phi(p))$ primitive roots mod $p$ and each primitive root must eventually be $-a$ at some power. But just from looking at a few small primes it's clear that many have more than $\phi(\phi(p))$ $x$s, which makes sense.

Edit 2: It seems that if we know the order of $-a$, let's call it $k$, then we know that every subgroup of order $\geq k$ such that $k$ divides the order will "hit" $-a$ $\frac{p-1}{\text{order}}$ times as $x$ goes from $1$ to $p(p-1)$. I think this means we can say that for all $\phi(k)$ $a$s of order $k$, there are $$\sum_{\substack{r\geq k \\ r\vert p-1 \\ k\vert r}} \frac{p-1}{r}\phi(r)$$ $x$s that $x^x\equiv -a$ mod $p$.

Comment: @hardmath nope, you're right, and that's a much easier way to express it. I initially had it as $p-a$ because that's how I was programming it into the computer because the modulus function returns a number between 0 and $p-1$.

Comment: I guess we can say a few things about the map $x^x$ from $\{1,\ldots,p (p-1)\}$ to $\mathbb Z \bmod p $, so e.g. the total solutions across all combined vales for $a $ is $p(p-1)$.

Comment: and of those $p(p-1)$, we know that there must be at least $\phi(p-1)$ for each $a$, so that leaves $p(p-1)-(p-1)\phi(p-1)=(p-1)(p-\phi(p-1))$ unaccounted for.

Comment: Our bookkeeping should be a little more comprehensive if we separate out the cases $a=0$.  Note that on the domain $x=1,\ldots,p (p-1)$, $x^x$ is zero precisely when  $x$ is a multiple of $p$, so there are $p-1$ such solutions.

Comment: I believe $x^x$ is zero precisely when $x$ is a multiple of $p$ and $x$ is not a multiple of $p-1$, which would give $p-2$ solutions (because $0^0\equiv 1$)